# Использование объекта класса в другом классе

Tags: c#, классы, объекты

Нужно, в зависимости от вычислений в одном классе, вывести результат в другом.

Как реализовать?

```
class Exam : Test
{
    public int mth, ph, pg;
    public double a;
    public void Print3()
    {
        int mth = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int ph = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int pg = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double a = (mth + ph + pg) / 3.0;
        Console.WriteLine("\nОценки за тест: Математика - {0}, Физика - {1}, Программирование - {2}. Ср.: {3}", mth, ph, pg, a);
    }
```

}

```
class FinalExam : Exam
    {
    public void Print4()
    {        
        if (a >= 3)
        {
            Console.Write("Финальный экзамен сдан! {0}", a);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Финальный экзамен не сдан! {0}", a);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае правильный подход был бы применить наследование: `FinalExam` — разновидность `Exam`. (*Обновление*: ага, вы так и сделали.) Метод `Print3` нужно назвать по-человечески и сделать виртуальным. (*Обновление*: это не обязательно, но было бы красивее.) В `FinalExam` этот метод должен вызывать метод родительского класса, после чего выводить свою дополнительную информацию. (*Обновление*: ну или если не переименовывать методы, то вызвать `Print3`.)

Ещё я бы отделили логику вычислений от логики вывода.

Код не даю, потому что вопрос явно относится к учебному заданию.

Comment: Изначально так и было. Я использовал ввод и вычисления в разных void-ах. Но к сожалению, как и переменная _а_, так и введённые данные не получается использовать из посторонних классов.

Виртуальные методы ещё не изучали.

Хотя я и вообще не очень понял Ваш ответ :(

Comment: «Ещё не изучали» — это не причина, разберитесь сами. А наследование изучали?

Comment: Понимаю, что не причина. Уже больше 5 часов сижу над модификацией этого кода. Свою функцию он выполняет, за исключением получения переменной из другого класса. Тут никак. Так бы и код разбил на сканирование, расчёт и вывод... Но никак не пойму. Наследование на самостоятельное изучение оставил преподаватель. Вот и сидим всей группой штудируем интернет, т.к. это завтра на 1 пару.

Comment: @Дмитрий: Так вроде же всё просто? Пусть Print4 в начале вызывает Print3. Покажите код, который работает с FinalExam.

Comment: @Дмитрий: Немного обновил ответ.

Comment: Я вот сейчас вообще запутался...
С FinalExam ничего не работает, просто вызов метода:
' FinalExam fex = new FinalExam();
 fex.Print4();'

Comment: @Дмитрий: Должно работать. Покажите, как у вас сейчас выглядит Print4.

Comment: Вот нужный кусок кода целиком: https://yadi.sk/i/_piPxbssjTT3f

Comment: @Дмитрий: А, понял! Хм :) Вам вовсе не нужны объекты `tr`, `ts` и `ex`! Вам нужен только `fex`, все методы вызывайте на нём. Дело в том, что `fex` **является** и экземпляром класса `Exam`, и `Test`, и т. д., вам не нужен отдельный `Test`. И повторите наследование! :-)

Comment: @Дмитрий: А в Print4 таки вызовите Print3 в начале.

Comment: Спасибо! Test нужен, т.к. это часть задания. 'fex' исправил.
Но программа так и не работает: В зависимости от среднего бала не выводится успешное/не успешное завершение финального экзамена.

Comment: @Дмитрий: покажите новый код

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/Bw_r1htEjTXGW

Comment: @Дмитрий: Не-не, вы не убрали tr, ts и ex. Уберите их! Вообще! Полностью! Метод Print1 есть и у fex.

Comment: Пардон, не тот код. Это предыдущая версия. Файл обновил, но толку от этого - 0

Comment: @Дмитрий: Сейчас гляну

Comment: @Дмитрий: Ну, у вас совсем мелочь. В Print3 вы присваиваете не в поле `a`, а в локальную переменную `a` :) Пишите просто `a = ...`, без `double`. И можно убрать virtual, по идее, раз вы этим не пользуетесь.

Comment: @Дмитрий: С этим изменением работает. Удачи вам!

Comment: Действительно работает! Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Дмитрий: Ну вот и хорошо :) Пожалуйста!

Comment: Сдал, получил 5. Повтори наследование, его и спросили) Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: @Дмитрий: Пожалуйста :) Удачи в обучении!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29806/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd------).